# Robotframework Is there any way to check element status when resource-id is the same

Tags: appium, robotframework, python-appium

Is there any way to check button status if resource-id is the same for all buttons? 
As I've shown in the picture, I have some buttons, that resource-id is the same, is it possible to toggle one button and check if the button status is changed?

I've read appium, selenium2 libraries and have no idea how to resolve my issue.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z24Ne.png)

Comment: Short answer - through xpath, and elememts' relative positions. Without the DOM no one will be able to assist you - so please add it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Get Webelements to get a list of all those buttons https://serhatbolsu.github.io/robotframework-appiumlibrary/AppiumLibrary.html#Get%20Webelements

Then you can reference them all individually.